# Displaying in-table thumbnail graphics in DataTables rendered in a shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny

Is there a somewhat feasible way to implement "in-table" thumbnail graphics in a [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/)/[DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)-based UI?

### Background and example

A couple of days ago I watched this [video](https://player.oreilly.com/videos/9781771373845) about what you can do with R on Azure and it sparked my imagination.

Besides the drag-and-drop-based modeling UI ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34713021/98969)), I really liked the fact that they display little thumbnails of descriptive stats graphics for each variable right in the table/matrix (see Minute 1:30 in the video):

[image]